# Slide Out Menu Bar in IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on slide out menu bar in objective-c. I have used some classes from this link https://github.com/arturdev/AMSlideMenu . I had made left menu. Now the problem which I'm facing is that the items in left menu are Home , AboutUs, Login/Register and Contact . if user get login the item login/register should change to logout and above the Home their should appear a cell of user profile or user till it remain login. If user press logout item it should logout and take us to home screen. Can anybody help me? I'm login the user data from web service. The left menu bar items r made in static cells.

Comment: You can use NSNotification Center to update the tableview cell and its selection

Comment: @NAVEEN KUMAR can u help me?

Comment: how man. @MinkleGarg

Comment: Reload the Tableview based on the web service response with NSNotification.

Comment: @AntonyRaphel actually I'm not getting it how to do

Comment: @Hamza Email me the project.

Comment: whats ur mail id? @MinkleGarg

Comment: @Hamza minkle.garg@gmail.com

Comment: sent. @MinkleGarg

Comment: @Hamza Yes, I got the email.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                             selector:@selector(refreshList)
                                                 name:@"refreshList"
                                               object:nil];


if ([[[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] dictionaryRepresentation] allKeys] containsObject:@"userlogging"]) {
        NSString *login = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"userlogging"];
        if ([login isEqualToString:@"loggedin"]) {
            NSArray *titles = @[@"Search Restaurants",@"Change Language",@"Sellers click here",@"Login"];
            checklogin = YES;
        }
    }
    else
    {
         NSArray *titles = @[@"Search Restaurants", @"My Cart", @"Favorite Restaurants",  @"Previous Orders",@"Change Language",@"Sellers click here", @"My Profile", @"Logout"];
         checklogin = NO;
    }
    [self.tableView reloadData];
```

Answer (score 0):

In left menu you should write a function that prepares the data source for your table view based on user state (log in/log out) and on log out menu reload table view.

e.g., a psuedocode to give you an idea:

```
var dataSource: [CustomMenuItemObject] = []
func prepareDataSource()
{
    dataSource = []
    if(MySessionManager.current.isUserLoggedIn())
    {
         dataSource.append (createMyProfileMenu())
         dataSource.append (createAboutUsMenu())
         dataSource.append (createLogoutMenu())
         dataSource.append (createContactMenu())
    }
    else
    { 
         dataSource.append (createHomeMenu())
         dataSource.append (createAboutUsMenu())
         dataSource.append (createLoginRegisterMenu())  
         dataSource.append (createContactMenu())
    }

    myTableView.reloadData()
}

func tableView(....numberOfRows...)
{
   return dataSource.count
}

func tableView(....cellForRow...)
{
   let cell == tableView.dequeue...
   ... 
   ...
   cell.updateCustomCellUsing(dataSource[indexPath.row])
   ...
   ...
   return cell
}

func createMyProfileMenu() -> CustomMenuItemModel
{
    let item = CustomMenuItemModel()
    item.titleText = "Profile"
    ...
    ...
    return item
}

..
.. // Further menu item creation code


func userDidLogout() // Delegate or NSNotification callback
{
   MySessionManager.current.clearUserDataFromSession()
   prepareDataSource()
   myTableView.reloadData() 
}

func userDidLogIn() // Delegate or NSNotification callback
{
   MySessionManager.current.setupUserInSession()
   prepareDataSource()
   myTableView.reloadData() 
}
```

On pressing logout either use NSNotification or delegate to reload the tableview in left menu view controller.

**EDIT: Objective-C version**

```
NSMutableArray dataSource = [NSMutableArray new];
-(void)prepareDataSource
{
    dataSource = [NSMutableArray new];
    if([[MySessionManager current] isUserLoggedIn])
    {
         [dataSource addObject:[self createMyProfileMenu]];
         [dataSource addObject:[self createAboutUsMenu]];
         [dataSource addObject:[self createLogoutMenu]];
         [dataSource addObject:[self createContactMenu]];
    }
    else
    { 
         [dataSource addObject:[self createHomeMenu]];
         [dataSource addObject:[self createAboutUsMenu]];
         [dataSource addObject:[self createLoginRegisterMenu]]; 
         [dataSource addObject:[self createContactMenu]];
    }

    [myTableView reloadData];
}

-(void)tableView(....numberOfRows...)
{
    return dataSource.count;
}

-(void)tableView(....cellForRow...)
{
   let cell == tableView.dequeue...
   ... 
   ...
   [cell updateCustomCellUsing(dataSource[indexPath.row])];
   ...
   ...
   return cell
}

-(CustomMenuItemModel *)createMyProfileMenu
{
    CustomMenuItemModel *item = [CustomMenuItemModel new];
    item.titleText = "Profile";
    ...
    ...
    return item
}

..
.. // Further menu item creation code


-(void)userDidLogout // Delegate or NSNotification callback
{
   [[MySessionManager current] clearUserDataFromSession];
   [self prepareDataSource];
   [myTableView reloadData];
}

-(void)userDidLogIn // Delegate or NSNotification callback
{
   [[MySessionManager current] setupUserInSession];
   [self prepareDataSource];
   [myTableView reloadData]; 
}
```

Comment: can u provide  example in objective -C then its helps him.

Comment: @NAVEENKUMAR, added obj-c version too.

Comment: These functions `userDidLogout`, `userDidLogIn` could be a notification post from App delegate, rest of the function should be the part of left menu view controller.